How to configure my firebase function runtime options during deployment?
I am trying to deploy a python firebase function that uses assertions. I want to disable these assertions in productions using "PYTHONOPTIMIZE": "1" or -o. Is there a way to configure the python runtime parameters during deployment
I could not find any docs that help with this issue.
